# Remote access to Ubuntu desktop from Windows laptop

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, remote, remote-access

I'm using an Ubuntu-based (18.04.04 LTS) desktop in Germany that's connected to the internet via ethernet cable. I would like to know if it's somehow possible to control this pc remotely from a Windows 10 based laptop which is located in Turkey. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Ozan

Comment: If you are on a same network then `nomachine` serves you the best. But I guess you are not on the same network, then you should use `teamviewer`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Teamviewer`

To install TeamViewer on your Ubuntu system, follow these steps:

1. Download the TeamViewer DEB package from https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/.
   If uncertain, pick the 64-bit package.

2.Open the teamviewer_15.x.yyyy_amd64.deb file with a double click.

The TeamViewer installation package will open in the Ubuntu Software Center.

3. Click on the Install button.
   The Authenticate dialog box will open.
4. Enter the administrative password.
5. Click on the Authenticate button.

TeamViewer will be installed.
The status within the Ubuntu Software Center changes to Installed.